# Android Handler.postDelayed precision

Tags: android

I use Handler.postDelayed for some kind of timeout (around 2 to 10 minutes) in my app. But I'm not sure about the precision. Is there anything which could substantially increase the actual delay for the execution? For example the runnable is executed after 5 minutes instead of 2 minutes? If the execution is additionally delayed by a few seconds if the actual delay is 2 to 10 minutes does not matter in my case.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Handler is not usually the best way to schedule a task in the future

Comment: imho 10 minute delays are good candidates for [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/)

Comment: The app accepts connections over BLE (peripheral mode) even if the app is in the background or the screen locked. If no connection is established within a certain time (the timeout) the app should stop accept connections (i.e. disable ble advertising). If a new connection is established, I renew the timeout by removing the runnable and post a new one with the initial delay.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at scheduled executor: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService

Use scheduleAtFixedRate or scheduleWithFixedDelay according to your needs.

Comment: How does that differ in terms of precision of the delay?

Comment: I thought by precision you meant when the precision of the event that triggers the runnable. If the result of the execution defines the next timeout (occasionally) you would want to prevent triggering the next runnable while the execution is on. So with scheduleWithFixedDelay you could shutdown and reschedule. I am sorry if I misunderstood you.